# What is the expected number of bins with at least one ball?

Tags: probability, expectation, binomial-distribution, balls-in-bins

Consider an random variable $X$, that follows a binomial distribution with parameters:

- $n=B$ (*i.e.* the number of attempts is $B$)
- $p=P$ (*i.e.* the probability of having a success is $P$)

So, $X \sim Bin(B,P)$.

Then, we read $X$.

After that, we create exactly $X$ bins and $X$ balls.

Finally, we toss the uniformly at random to the bins.
All the tosses are independent from each other.

How can I obtain lower bounds on the expected number of bins with at least one ball?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you find an expression for this expectation under extra condition $X=k$?

Comment: @drhab for an already known $X$, yes. My problem is exactly for a random $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X = m$. Let $Y_{i}$ denote a random variable, such that:

$$ Y_{i} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & \text{if the }i\text{-th bin has at least one ball} \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Then, we have
$$
\Pr[Y_i = 0 \mid X = m] = \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^m
$$
because all $m$ balls are tossed into other $m-1$ bins.
Therefore,
$$
\Pr[Y_i = 1 \mid X = m] = 1 - \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^m
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y_i \mid X = m] = 1 - \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^m \geq 1 - \frac{1}{e}
$$

Let $Z$ denote the number of bins with at least $1$ ball.
Then, by the [*linearity of the expectation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value):
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z \mid X = m] = \mathbb{E}[Y_1 + Y_2 + \cdots + Y_m \mid X = m] \geq m\left(1 - \frac{1}{e}\right)
$$

Thus, by the [*law of total expectation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Z] =& \sum_{m=0}^B \mathbb{E}[Z \mid X = m]\cdot\Pr[X=m]  \\
\geq &\sum_{m=0}^B m\left(1 - \frac{1}{e}\right)\cdot\Pr[X=m] \\
=& \left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right) \sum_{m=0}^Bm\cdot\Pr[X=m] \\
=& \left(1 - \frac{1}{e}\right) \cdot\mathbb{E}[X] = \left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right)BP
\end{align}

Comment: Before I accept it, I'll look at it very carefully. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: @guilhermemtr this is what I had in mind.

Comment: @drhab, nice. I am sorry if my question was not clear enough right away so that you could answer right away as well. But thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: @NP-hard your answer makes sense to me. Let me double check it (I am very careful with these things, since these results are important to me).

Comment: @NP-hard, do you mind if I edit your answer, just to add which theorems and lemmas are used in some of the steps? For newbies like me, that is important.

Comment: @guilhermemtr Please edit the answer if it makes you understand the answer better.

Comment: @NP-hard, does it look ok to you?

Comment: @guilhermemtr Nice. Looks good to me. Thanks for improving the answer.